# Subplot not showing 2 graphs

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, canvas, tkinter

Here is the result of my code.

[image: Here is the result of my code]

**These are the libraries**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

I got a problem when I want to plot 4 graphs with the `subplot(2,2,x)` look a the code.

```
    #Canvas 1
    self.f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
    self.k = self.f.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
    self.k.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,0])
    self.plot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, self.root)
    self.plot.show()
    self.plot.get_tk_widget().place(x=40,y=250)


    # Canvas 2
    self.f1 = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
    self.k1 = self.f.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
    self.k1.plot([0,9,0,9,0],[6,7,8,9,0])


    # Canvas 3
    self.f2 = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
    self.k2 = self.f2.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
    self.k2.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[0,9,0,9,0])


    # Canvas 4
    self.f3 = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
    self.k3 = self.f3.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)
    self.k3.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[0,9,0,9,0])
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: It was already answer, but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second canvas is being added to the first figure `f`, that is why it is shown. It doesn't really make much sense to use subplots if each of them has its own figure.

The problem should be solved adding all the subplots to `self.f`.